# cookies are not getting set in my layout page in ny next app using app router

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to delete a cookie named auth_token from within a catch statement in my Next.js application. The deletion logic is placed within a layout.js file. Despite trying various approaches, including the use of next/headers, I've been unable to successfully remove the cookie. Below is the implementation I've been working with:

```
async function deleteCookie(name) {
  'use server';
  cookies().set(name, '', { expires: new Date(0)});
  console.log('deleted cookie')
}


async function getData() {
  const nextCookies = cookies();
  const token = nextCookies.get('auth_token')?.value;

  if (token) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`${process.env.API_URL}/me`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
      });
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      deleteCookie('auth_token');
    }
  }
}


export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const user = await getData() || null;

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <UserProvider initialUser={user}>
          {children}
        </UserProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

However, when executing this code, I'm met with the following error:

```
unhandledRejection: e3 [Error]: Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies#cookiessetname-value-options
    at Proxy.callable (D:\odede\Documents\Next\clubbera-final\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page-experimental.runtime.dev.js:34:370578)        
    at $$ACTION_0 (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/layout.js:34:61)
    at deleteCookie (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/layout.js:30:23)
    at getData (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/layout.js:53:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async RootLayout (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/layout.js:58:18)
```

This suggests that cookies can only be modified in specific contexts, which I've tried to adhere to without success. Has anyone faced a similar challenge or can offer insight into how to correctly implement cookie deletion in this scenario? Any advice or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation is being called from a context that is not permitted for modifying cookies (during server-side rendering or from client-side code).

Move your `deleteCookie` logic to an API route:

Create a new file under `app/api/deleteCookie/route.ts` add following:

```js
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

export async function POST(request) {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  cookieStore.delete('yourCookieName');

  return new Response('Cookie deleted', { status: 200 });
}
```

Modify your `getData` function to call this API route when needed:

```js
    async function getData() {
      const nextCookies = cookies();
      const token = nextCookies.get('auth_token')?.value;
    
      if (token) {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get(`${process.env.API_URL}/me`, {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
          });
          return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
          // Call the API route to delete the cookie
          await fetch('/api/deleteCookie', { method: 'POST' });
        }
      }
    }
```